# Девять классов с коридорами

Tags: фразеология

***Ой, да что с него взять, у него ведь девять классов с коридорами!***

Что означает выражение "с коридорами": с прогулами? со временем, проведённым в коридоре в результате удаления с урока?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее уж с прогулами.

Здесь напрашивается понимание "класс" = "классная комната". Так что "столько-то классов с коридорами" это просто показатель неполноценности, натяжки в определении уровня образования.

Сюда же - "коридорное образование", весьма популярный ныне термин для обозначения того, что Пушкин назвал "мы все учились понемногу // чему-нибудь и как-нибудь". До коридора из класса, конечно, что-то долетает из рассказа учителя, но что и как при этом усваивается?!

(+)

Коли пошли версии, давайте расставим все точки над i.

Фраза эта в варианте "Девять классов и три коридора" звучит из уст Жеглова - на вопрос об образовании. Очень может быть, что фильм и есть первоисточник выражения.
Но тогда вариант "второгодничества" вроде как отпадает, Жеглов был достаточно образованным для своей профессии человеком.
А вот коридор как символ недостаточности школьного образования вполне себе годится, остальное - в коридоре доучивал. Примерно в таком духе и отвечают в Интернете.

Хотя ваше понимание тоже не противоречит общему смыслу, даже придаёт ему определенный шарм, но, боюсь, такая мера, как удаление с уроков, не могла быть настолько распространенной, чтобы стать основой выражения.

Comment: А может, здесь просто ставка на неразрывную лексическую пару "класс - коридор" в значении "помещения"? Добавляют слово "коридор" как пару к "классу" и добиваются иронического значения фразы. Игра слов? Каламбур?

Comment: *просто ставка на неразрывную лексическую пару "класс - коридор"* - так я это совсем не исключаю. Наоборот, первым же вариантом нечто подобное и написал, даже еще без Жеглова.

Answer (score 1):

Слышать это выражение доводилось, а читаю впервые. Не возьмусь утверждать, но кажется, оно «моложе» так же неписанного - «господи, помоги тупице учиться (ГПТУ)». 
Первый контекст связан с практикой назначения повторного года обучения по решению педсовета школы. Класс это год обучения, «коридор» - год повторного обучения (второгодник).
Второй контекст связан с  местом и источником получения знаний, навыков. «Класс» - это аудитория и школьный учитель, «коридоры» - улица, ватага, участковый уполномоченный.

Comment: *«коридор» - год повторного обучения* - что-то не сталкивался. Есть убедительные цитаты? И потом, а как это вяжется с "коридорной формой обучения"? Тут-то уж явная связь, не придуманная, как в случае с ГПТУ.

Comment: Поскольку примеров употребления для выражения «коридорная форма обучения» не приведено, допускаю, что это саркастическое преобразование широко известного - «заочная форма обучения», что более применимо к понятию «система высшего образования».

Comment: Вы можете допускать все что угодно. А я - то, что вы не удосужились сходить за примерами в гугл.Впрочем, не в том дело. Вы считаете, что в этих двух случаях использования "коридор", "коридорный" несет разный смысл?! Мне подобное кажется натянутым. Я про *"девять классов и три  коридора"* и *"коридорное обучение"*.

Comment: Сложно признать «явной» связь выражений "9 классов с коридорами" и "коридорная форма обучения". Если связь и просматривается, то только на уровне примитивной сортировки хохм по разделам: от Никулина, про Чапаева, со ловом «коридор»…
По «ГПТУ», более авторитетного источника не нашлось: https://otvet.mail.ru/question/6927749